# what is standard approach to create a responsive website using javascript,php ajax and perhaps zend framework

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework, validation

I am working on a web system currently and plans to heavily use JavaScript with AJAX to make the user interface more friendlier, not fancy as such.

The JavaScript will be used for client side form validation, data loading from server and creating proper content with the result, also to for floating windows during add/edit or external references.

Here is a scenerio that could clearify my question.

> A user wants to update card but instead of jumping to another page to verify the available colors, size and prizes of product, those information are shown in a floating window and changes in the floating window can affect the underlying one.

My question is :

**1.** What are some of the approaches to encounter this situation?
　**2.** Are there any helpful tips, tricks and links on this subject?

I am comfortable with JavaScript, PHP, and Zend. I would appreciate any advice, tips, and tricks, problem solving approach to handle a situation like this! Thanks in advance.
Hope this make sense.

Comment: You might want to post this at `http://webmasters.stackexchange.com` instead.

Comment: I did but as it turned out, it was voted down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a js framework that add structure to your client-side code ( try ext-js , backbone , angular , embers , etc ... ) and a set of widgets (kendoUI , ext-js , jquery-ui , dojo ... ) . Zend has a tight integration with Dojo so you might want to check it , you can also check ZendX jquery for jquery-ui integration for forms. 
With the Dojo integration you might not need a mvc framework on the top of that , it depends on what you want exactly.

good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am going to look into the ZendX jQuery because my client insist on restricting the js libraries to only jQuery.

Comment: ok , however be sure to check zend_dojo because the integration is tighter ,it takes some time to understand how it works , but once you get it ,really you can work really really fast.